# How to change Product Stock Alert email template in custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, product, email-templates, manage-stock

I want to change email template of stock alert but I could  found only single variable in the template file "alertGrid". Please tell me how I will change the alertGrid layout. So, I can change the email template.

Comment: can you specify what information you want to chage or need to modify.

Comment: I want to change the layout of "alertGrid" html, If I will get how to override "alertGrid" html in my theme then i can change layout.

Comment: Please access this url https://misfitlondon.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/Products_Back_In_Stock.jpg , i want this type of layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable which is used in email template `{{var alertGrid}}` is set from this files.

```
app\code\core\Mage\ProductAlert\Model\Email.php.
```

Arround line no. 229 there is function

```
public function send()
```

in this function this variable is set, you need to look here how you want change.

And if you want to change in phtml file.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\productalert\stock.phtml
```

this file called when email send.

Overide that file in your theme, you need to just copy that file to your current theme in same path like

```
app\design\frontend\[Your There]\template\email\productalert\stock.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick response. Sorry sir, but i don't want to change in any model file or controller file , Can i change from phtml file. Because i have to include little bit content and a button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to check this function, so you find which template file is called. So you need to change into that file.

Comment: I update my answer, please check so you get path of phtml file which called while email send.

Comment: Thanks, you are really too experience in magento :) . I copy the "stock.phtml" from core and paste at this path in my theme /app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/template/email/productalert/stock.phtml and also change some content in this file but it still get content from core stock.phtml. Is am skip any config setting for override?

Comment: sir, Please tell me how i will override the stock.phtml file in my custom theme.

Comment: I update my answer. And If this help you please accept it as solution so it help other in community as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66700/discussion-between-dineshkashera-and-dhiren-vasoya).